# Objective C NSDictionary JSON in One line

Tags: objective-c

i'm working on one objective C application where i'm taking JSON data and i need to insert this data(date) inside Dictionary fillDefaultColors. My fillDefaultColors should be in format like this:

```
self.fillDefaultColors = @{    @"2017/06/18":greenColor,
                               @"2017/06/19":orangeColor,
                               @"2017/06/20":greenColor,
                               ...
                               };
```

but when i print in console log they are each in separate row and in application i can see colour just for last item from JSON

```
2017-06-19 15:30:12.310 CalendarTest[1905:364525] {
    "2017/06/20" = "greenColor";
}
2017-06-19 15:30:12.311 CalendarTest[1905:364525] {
    "2017/06/18" = "orangeColor";
}
```

So in application i see background for last date in console 2017/06/18

Here is my code

```
NSError *error = nil;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://..."];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];

   if(!error)
    {
        NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                              JSONObjectWithData:data
                              options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                              error:&error];

       NSMutableArray *array= [json objectForKey:@"horses"];

       for(int i=0; i< array.count; i++)
        {
            NSDictionary *horsedata = [array objectAtIndex:i];
            NSString *date = [horsedata objectForKey:@"date"];
            NSNumber *averagetemp = [horsedata objectForKey:@"averagetemperature"];
            if([averagetemp isEqual:@(28)]) {tempColor = greenColor;} else {
                tempColor = orangeColor;
            }
            self.fillDefaultColors = @{date: tempColor};
            NSLog(@"%@", _fillDefaultColors);

       }

   }

JSON: {"horses":[{"id":1,"name":"Horse","date":"2017/06/17","averagetemperature":28},{"id":1,"name":"Horse","date":"2017/06/18","averagetemperature":25}]}

Thanks
```

Comment: `self.fillDefaultColors = @{date: tempColor};` you are overwriting each time `self.fillDefaultColors`. `[self.fillDefaultColors setObject:tempColor forKey:date];`, and you need somewhere to do  `self.fillDefaultColors = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];` Note that if you have some `date` value that are equals, the `object` (value) will be replaced since there is unicity for keys.

Comment: Apart from the issue **never** load data from a remote URL with a synchronous method like `dataWithContentsOfURL`. It will block the current thread. And why do you pass the option `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` but assign the result to an immutable object?

Comment: @vadian I'm new to objective c and i found this code on internet tutorial...

Comment: Very bad tutorial, look for a better one, unfortunately there are no quality checks and every amateur can distribute his superficial knowledge.

Comment: @Larme it's working, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it s because you are allocating a new dictionary in each iteration:

```
self.fillDefaultColors = @{date: tempColor};
```

you need to append instead:

```
   NSMutableArray *array= [json objectForKey:@"horses"];
   self.fillDefaultColors = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
   for(int i=0; i< array.count; i++)
    {
        NSDictionary *horsedata = [array objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *date = [horsedata objectForKey:@"date"];
        NSNumber *averagetemp = [horsedata objectForKey:@"averagetemperature"];
        if([averagetemp isEqual:@(28)]) {tempColor = greenColor;} else {
            tempColor = orangeColor;
        }

        [self.fillDefaultColors setObject:tempColor forKey:date];
        NSLog(@"%@", _fillDefaultColors);

   }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the same solution as in Hussein's answer but with *Modern Objective-C Syntax* – which has been introduced at least 5 years ago.

```
NSArray *horses = json[@"horses"];
self.fillDefaultColors = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary *horsedata in horses)
{
    NSString *date = horsedata[@"date"];
    NSNumber *averagetemp = horsedata[@"averagetemperature"];
    self.fillDefaultColors[date] = (averagetemp.integerValue == 28) ? greenColor : orangeColor;

    NSLog(@"%@", _fillDefaultColors);
}
```